# Why some solution are excluded in solving equality involving absolute value function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

For example I have to solve this equation
$$|x-1|+|2x+4|=5.$$
I have been taught that I have to make an table and find the cases in which $x-1$ and $2x+4$ are going to be positive and negative, both negative for the interval $(-\infty;-2)$; first negative and second positive for $(-2;1)$; and both positive for $(1;+\infty)$ in this case, and then solve for $x$ in each case and you get three results: $-8/3$ for $x \in (-\infty;-2)$, $0$ for $x \in (-2;1)$ and $2/3$ for $x \in (1;+\infty)$.

Here is what I don't understand. Why only $-8/3$ and $0$ are supposedly solutions and $2/3$ is not? I was told its because $x \notin (1;+\infty)$. But that doesn't really make sense for me, can anyone explain this in more detail?

Comment: If $x\geq 1$ then $|x-1|=x-1$, if $x\leq 1$ then $|x-1|=-(x-1)=-x+1$. You can use expression $x-1$ for $|x-1|$ only for $x\geq 1$, it is not appropriate for $x<1$.

Comment: "*why 2/3 is not*"  If you plug $\frac{2}{3}$ in to your original equation, you get $|\frac{2}{3}-1|+|2\cdot \frac{2}{3} + 4|$ which simplifies as $5+\frac{2}{3}\neq 5$.  You should always check that your solutions are actually solutions.  More specifically, you could have known ahead of time $\frac{2}{3}$ is not a valid solution since it came from the case where you considered "*If $x$ was bigger than $1$...*" and you arrived at the conclusion "*then $x=\frac{2}{3}$*"... but of course $x$ cannot simultaneously be bigger than $1$ *and* equal to $\frac{2}{3}$, those contradict each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand what the issue is, let consider this simpler example

> $$|x+1|+1=0$$

and for $\color{magenta}{x\ge -1}$ we have

$$|x+1|+1=0 \iff x+2=0 \iff x=-2$$

but the possible solution obtained is out of the interval we have considered, that is $\color{magenta}{-2<-1}$ and indeed this value is not a solution for the original equation

$$|-2+1|+1=1+1=2\neq 0$$

Comment: Thank you, with your simple example it is so simple to imagine different scenarios like |x+1|+n=0, n>0, there will be no solution ever, as |x+1| will always be positive, and for |x+1|+n, n≤0, there will always be a solution and x, the solution, will always be in the desired interval x≥-1. Wish one day I will reach your level and be able to simplify the most difficult concepts :)

Comment: @NegoitaMihai Yes indeed this is exactly the point! The original equation $|x+1|+1=0$ clearly has not solutions but for the auxiliary equation $x+2=0$ has a solution.

Comment: Hi, I think that my questions or answers are definite as low levels. I make very much for my students but i have few answers from differenti users. Best regards.

Comment: Hi @Sebastiano, are you referring to your last question? You could put a bounty on that or maybe ask to the MSE [Math Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: @NegoitaMihai I just mean that eliminating the absolute value (i.e. auxiliary equation) we can obtain spurious solutions, that is out of the interval we are considering to eliminate the absolute value from the original equation.

Comment: Hi very kind. Thank you very much for the community that i not know. Now i understand the reason for the missed answers for my questions. Now i put a bounty.

Answer (score 3):

Because $\frac23\notin(1,\infty)$. Note that you got $\frac23$ while assuming that $x\in(1,\infty)$. Therefore, a solution that you get outside that interval doesn't have to be a solution of your equation.